# New Line added at the end of the text while converting from HTML to Plain Text

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa, plaintext, richtext

We have a Text editor in our application which supports both Rich and Plain Text. So, we are using WebView for displaying the RichText and NSTextView for displaying the Plain Text and the content is saved in the HTML format. I am facing a problem of addition of a new Line at the end of the Text while converting from HTML.

Sample HTML: `<html><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">CR1<br><div><br></div><div>CR2</div></body></html>`

Below is the conversion Code From HTML to NSString

```
- (NSString *)convertHTMLToPlain:(NSString *)str {
    NSString *finalString = nil;

    NSAttributedString *attrString = nil;
    NSData *theData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

    if (nil != theData) {
        NSDictionary *encodingDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) forKey:@"CharacterEncoding"];
        attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:theData documentAttributes:&encodingDict];

        NSString *result = [attrString string];

        NSString *specialCharecter = @"\u2028";
        if ([result containsString:specialCharecter]) {
            finalString = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:specialCharecter
                                                            withString:@""];
        } else {
            finalString = result;
        }
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

The result’s value is displayed below:

[image: Result]

You could see there is no `<br>` tag at the end but it still adds a new line but if I open the HTML File in webView it displays correctly. Could someone tell me why is that kind of a behavior. How can I fix that?

Comment: I think this is same as <br> , which is used to display on the screen , it is only there to format the output, similar to \t(tab) and I think this is not an issue

Comment: @Rahul Singh Try This... `NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[YOUR_HTML_STRING dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];`

Comment: @NiravKotecha: The issue still persists. A new line is still getting appended on conversion from HTML to Plain Text.